# How can I execute some commands in a shell script with `sudo` and others not?

Tags: shell-script, sudo

I'm about to write a script that requires some commands be executed with sudo and others be executed as the current user. I believe that if I sudo the script with `sudo script`, then all the command in it will run as sudo. How to I exclude some of them to run as the current user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix each command that needs `sudo` in the script with `sudo`, in the script, and run the script as normal. (This can be a bit surprising when the first password prompt comes up, so it’s worth adding a message before the first `sudo` in the script).

Comment: This is actually going to run on Ubuntu within AWS, which never asks for the password, I don't know why. tyvm.

Comment: @Chuck then you are probably logging in as root. Don't do that! In any case, if you are logging in as root, using `sudo` or not will make no difference.

Comment: I appreciate that tip, but I'm certain I'm not logging in as root. Some commands require sudo when I'm logged in and won't work without it.

Comment: Your `sudo` is probably set up to not require a password then; look for `NOPASSWD` in `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: This doesn't work well if the one or more of the commands takes a long time. You start the process, walk away, only to find it's paused waiting for you to type in your password again, repeat for each long command.